# Background Skype calls via URI?

Tags: ios, skype

On iOS, is it possible to launch a Skype voice call via URI while maintaining my app in the foreground?

If so, is it also possible to launch Skype via URI with speakerphone enabled?

(Why?  I'm trying to support voice communication while also performing a collaborative task in my app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to the official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745885%28v=office.15%29.aspx). There isn't any options to be included in the Skype URL.

The only supported call is the default one:

```
- (IBAction)skypeMe:(id)sender
{
  BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
  if(installed)
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
  }
  else
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
  }
}
```